# dismissViewControllerAnimated only works after tapping TableView Row second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my iOS App, i present a UItableViewController using

```
...
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
...
```

Now after i tap a row in my tableview, i want to dismiss my tableviewcontroller:

```
#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:^(void) {
        NSLog(@"dismissed");
    }];
}
```

Now my problem:
dismissViewControllerAnimated works as intended, but I have to tap the row 2 times. The first time i tap the row nothing happens.

Observations so far:

- I tap a row one time: Nothing happens
- I tap a row  2 times: TableviewController dismisses, "dismissed" gets logged
- I tap a row  one time and dismiss the Tableview by tapping somewhere outside the modal: "dismissed" gets logged

Seems like the completion block will be "scheduled" even if I tap only one time. But the dismissing doesn't happen.

Does anyone know what cause this problem?

Comment: Sounds like didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is not getting called all on the first press?  Do you have any buttons or text-input fields inside the row that would be intercepting touch events?

Comment: @par didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is getting called. I already put a breakpoint there and tested it.

Comment: Is the tableViewDelegate the *presenting* view controller or is it the UITableViewController?  You need to call dismissViewController from the presenting view controller so try possibly [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated...]

Comment: try `[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:...]`

Comment: Thanks. It worked (after it did it on the main thread). :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to par and ShahiM I got the solution: I had to dismiss on the Main Thread.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dismissAndshowPdf) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void) dismissAndshowPdf {
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:^(void) {
         NSLog(@"dismissed");
    }];
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense because `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is already being called on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Call deselectRowAtIndexPath before dismissing controller

Answer (score 1):

As @rmaddym said `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called on the main thread. The magic is on calling `[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:]` instead of `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:]`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `self.definesPresentationContext = true` to your `UITableViewController`

This solved the issue for me.